# How to migrate from Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 20 without SpringBoot but with a embedded Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin20, hilla

The problem I have with my current **Vaadin 8** project is that I have a java entry class which starts 2 instances of a **Tomcat** with some static and dynamic contexts.

With **Vaadin 8** I used to link all the libs statically on Eclipse so I didn't use a pom.xml file before but in order to update the current workflow I defined all those libraries on the pom.xml file. Now that I'm using a pom.xml file I realise that the whole frontend is started with the **vaadin-maven-plugin** and I don't really know how to get work the frontend (**Fusion and Flow**) with the embedded **Tomcat** Server but without **SpringBoot**.

I think the vaadin team wants the community to use **SpringBoot** more and more.

So how would you integrate **Vaadin 20** (Fusion and Flow) + a embedded **Tomcat** Server but without **SpringBoot**? or do you recommend to migrate also to **SpringBoot**? I saw many annotations that  are needed for the **Vaadin 20** **Fusion** part and just work with **SpringBoot**.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use Vaadin 21 /w Fusion, then SpringBoot is a mandatory requirement at the moment. However if you use Vaadin 21 /w Flow only, i.e. traditional Vaadin Java way, then SpringBoot is not mandatory to use.